# What's the best approach to do this?

Tags: url-rewriting, multi-language

I want to start a new site where I want the main page to be a static page showing information about myself, a kind of resumee without personal details.

Then, there would be a `site.com/blog/` where I occasionally write to demonstrate the skills listed on the static page.

Finally, I want all of this to be in English and Spanish.

---

So far, I changed the static front page to "About me" and then I created a new empty page "Blog", and chose it as posts page. When I click on "Blog", I get to the posts page but the URL looks like `/?page_id=11`. I would like it to look as I said before (`/blog/`).

About the language, I see there are multiple plugins that translate the content. I'm interested in write it by myself, and the only plugin that seems to allow this is qTranslate, which doesn't work with the latest WP version. The only idea that comes to my mind is to do two separate installations on `site.com/en` and `site.com/es`. What else could I do?

Comment: Change the permalink settings but really this question is best asked on the WordPress.org forums as its not a Development question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about the permalinks you should go to settings->permalinks and change permalinks to "post name". then you can see "/blog/" for your blog page.
for translating your theme you dont need any plugins. you should work with .po files. go to your theme folder and then "languages". there you can see translation files inside this folder. you can create your own translation files but actually you need a software like "[poedit](https://poedit.net/download)". it's free to download and use. good luck

Comment: it seems that something has to be changed on the server to allow any other permalink, because I get a "Not found", which is normal as /var/www/blog doesn't exist.

Comment: nothing needs to be change in server. just do the first part and save changes. after saving permalinks '.htaccess' file automaticly change by wordpress.

Comment: if you keep getting not found error try to delete ".htaccess" file from your public html folder and save permalinks again to let wordpress create .htaccess file again. please note that you should backup your .htaccess file first.

Comment: I keep getting the error even after delete .htaccess.

Comment: the last thing we can think of is that your wordpress installation doesnt have permission to change .htaccess file! my site has 644 permission for .htaccess file.

Comment: same, and owned by www-data (Debian server). Anyway, this is another problem and the solution to my question was what you said, to change permalink and to change .po files.

Comment: Solved the rewriting issue. I needed to change AllowOverride to All in Apache.